# solution crashes when one textbox is not filled in

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, vba

currently, I'm trying doing a code to add a new student to the database table. but when one of the textboxes is not filled when pressing submit, the solution crashes. please show me a way to write my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class AddNewStudent
    Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand
    Dim con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ASSIGNMENT\vbnassignmentfinal.accdb;"
    Dim cmdDelete As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmdSearch As New OleDbCommand
    Private Sub AddNewStudentSD_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = con
        cnnOLEDB.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        txtsem.ResetText()
        txtsfn.ResetText()
        txtsid.ResetText()
        txtsln.ResetText()
        txtsph.ResetText()
        txtint.ResetText()
        cmbgen.ResetText()


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnhome.Click
        UserHomepage.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsubmit.Click
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "Insert into student Values(" + txtsid.Text + ",'" + txtint.Text + "','" + txtsfn.Text + "','" + txtsln.Text + "', '" + cmbgen.Text + "', " + txtsph.Text + ", '" + txtsem.Text + "');"
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to proceed?", "Proceed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If DialogResult.Yes Then
            UserHomepage.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf DialogResult.No Then
            Me.Show()
            UserHomepage.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsubmit.Click
     cnnOLEDB.Open()
            cmdInsert.CommandText = "Insert into student Values(" + txtsid.Text + ",'" + txtint.Text + "','" + txtsfn.Text + "','" + txtsln.Text + "', '" + cmbgen.Text + "', '" + txtsph.Text + "', '" + txtsem.Text + "');"
            cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnnOLEDB.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to proceed?", "Proceed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
            If DialogResult.Yes Then
                UserHomepage.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            ElseIf DialogResult.No Then
                Me.Show()
                UserHomepage.Hide()
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: i tried your method sk, but my solution is still crashing when pressing submit with a n empty textbox

Comment: allow null option on table or pass some default value suppose empty

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Visual Studio has the `NZ function` like MS-Access does in its VBA environment.

You can create your own function to mimic it:

```
Public Shared Function Nz(ByVal Value As Object, Optional ByVal Default as Object = String.Empty) As Object
    If Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Value) Then
        Return Default
    Else
        Return Value
    End If
End Function
```

And then modify your dynamic SQL line of code to convert any Null text fields to empty strings.

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "Insert into student Values(" + NZ(txtsid.Text,"") + _
 ",'" + NZ(txtint.Text,"") + "','" + NZ(txtsfn.Text,"") + "','" + _
 NZ(txtsln.Text,"") + "', '" + NZ(cmbgen.Text,"") + "', '" + NZ(txtsph.Text,"") _
 + "', '" + NZ(txtsem.Text,"") + "');"
```